# Are there any circuits to get output as a sum of a set of current sources?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, current-source, circuit-design

I have 3 current sources (I1, I2 and I3) and I need to get an output of linear summation of the current of these sources.

Iout = aI1+bI2+cI3

where a,b and c are gain factors (like 1 to 10 and are constants). I1, I2 and I3 ranges from tens of uAs to hundreds of mAs.

I need to drive a Laser LED, target is to keep its voltage constant and vary the current depending on the light power required. Therefore I think converting current into voltage and back to current using a resistor is not an option I have. Required bandwidth is about 10MHz (This bandwidth will be applied to one of the input current components, say I1).

Are there any circuits to do this job.

Comment: A TIA opamp circuit would give you a voltage (that is the sum of the currents.)  You could turn that into a current with a resistor.

Comment: This is called a weighted sum.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the current source (compliance/impedance), a humble resistor might do a good job of converting current to voltage. Then a summing amplifier.

Comment: I need to drive a Laser LED, target is to keep its voltage constant and vary the current depending on the light power required. Therefore I think converting current into voltage and back to current using a resistor is not an option I have.

Comment: Add that information to the question. I actually thought it was a homework question. But now it sounds like a real application. You also need to specify the required signal bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you very much. Required bandwidth is about 10MHz. Updated the question.

Comment: What is your source? Is it a diode? What type?

Comment: They will be standard current source ICs.

Comment: And what is the range of the currents? uA, mA, A or tens of amps? You really need to improve your question.

Comment: Your task does not look that simple. In order to give a reasonable advise, pls clarify these questions:

Comment: 1. What are ranges of I1 I2 I3: are they from 0 to 1 mA or...?

Comment: 2. Are the coefficients a b c constants (hardcoded by components)?

Comment: 3. The bandwidth 10 MHz applies to all currents I1 I2 I3 or to one current only?

Comment: 4. What are the values of coefficients a b c: i.e., what is the output current range?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well considering your question, here is a general outline for something that we could make work. The ideal current sources represent the input sources, (note that they are fairly small and the assumption is that yours are as well).

The configuration made by Q1 and Q2 is a simple current amplifier, where the output current at the collector is **approximately** the betas of the NPN and PNP times the input current.

The collector currents of the PNP transistors both flow into R4, so effectively we have created a current summer.

This isn't intended to be incredibly thorough, there are a lot of things left for you to consider. If this in turn leads to a working setup, please update the answer to reflect your changes.

You would also need to regulate the voltage at the output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPZskM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>